# Finding the closed form $\phi(n) / n^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

$\sum_{1}^{\inf}{\phi(n)/n^x}$ Get an closed form expression for the value in terms of x.

Also, is there a closed form for the function $f(x) = \sum_{1}^{\inf}{\pi(n)/n^x}$. If you use PNT you can get some expressions in terms of li integrals but that's probably a dead end and since PNT is only an approximation its not the actual function.

Comment: There is no smallest $x$. The totient series converges for $x > 2$ (more generally, $\operatorname{Re} x > 2$ if we don't restrict to real $x$). This is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244218/totient-function-series-diverges). The series with $\pi(n)$ coefficients converges on the same half-plane.

Comment: Whoops. Fixed it.

Comment: The biggest value it can take is $\zeta(x-1)-\zeta(x)$

Comment: Assuming that phi(x) is always x-1. Im going to try something with bounds to get a good approximation

Comment: FYI, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\phi(n)}{n^x}}=\frac{\zeta(x-1)}{\zeta(x)}$$

Comment: How'd you get that?

Comment: Already answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2244827/44121 there is no minimum exponent, $x=2$ is the infimum of the exponents ensuring convergence.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio please read the entire question before closing it. It's not a duplicate (although the first part is), the second series, with $\pi(n)$, is not in the "duplicate" question

Comment: There is no nice closed form for such a series since $\pi(n)$ is not a multiplicative function, but the PNT gives a sharp bound on the average value of $\pi(n)$, so that is trivial to approximate.

Comment: $\pi(n)\sim\frac{n}{\log n}$, hence the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\pi(n)}{n^x}$ is convergent iff $x>2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer, just an explaination on the first part. Let's look at

$$\left(\frac1{1^s}+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\frac1{4^s}+\cdots\right)\left(\frac{\phi(1)}{1^s}+\frac{\phi(2)}{2^s}+\frac{\phi(3)}{3^s}+\frac{\phi(4)}{4^s}+\cdots\right)$$

how many times do we get a $\frac1{n^s}$? Well, for each $d\mid n$, we have the $k$ with $dk=n$, so that $\frac1{k^s}\frac{\phi(d)}{d^s}=\frac{\phi(d)}{n^s}$, so we get each $\frac1{n^s}$ exactly $\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)$ times, and, well, that's simply $n$. Thus, the above product is

\begin{align}
&\ \ \ \ \ \ \left(\frac1{1^s}+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\frac1{4^s}+\cdots\right)\left(\frac{\phi(1)}{1^s}+\frac{\phi(2)}{2^s}+\frac{\phi(3)}{3^s}+\frac{\phi(4)}{4^s}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{1^s}+\frac{2}{2^s}+\frac{3}{3^s}+\frac{4}{4^s}+\cdots\\
&=\frac{1}{1^{s-1}}+\frac1{2^{s-1}}+\frac1{3^{s-1}}+\frac1{4^{s-1}}+\cdots\\
\end{align}

so that $\zeta(s)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\phi(n)}{n^s}=\zeta(s-1)$. It follows that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\phi(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}$$

and so that only converges for $s>2$.